# make html table element <td></td> editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I pull info from a database table and place it into an HTML table.  I want to allow the user to click on a number in the table and be able to edit it.  I used jquery to make an event for click but when I use `<textarea>` it enlarges the cell and messes up the look of the whole table.  I've tried `<input>` and it does the same.  Any way that the table cell itself can just be turned into an input?  Here's 2 screenshots, first with the table, second to show how the table gets skewed when an input is added.
[Screenshot of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYCVj.png)
[Screenshot of Table with Textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwAz3.png)

The question is what is my best option for editing text. `<textarea>` makes the cell larger and honestly it looks ugly... `contenteditable` doesn't work with IE from the sounds of it, which disqualifies it as an option. My end goal is to save the value back to the database also after its entered which is why I was trying a click with jquery, so it would be easy to add more code to shoot the text back to the DB afterwards

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $query= "SELECT * FROM schedule";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $scheduletext="<table>";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $b=1;
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $scheduletext.="<tr>";
            $a=1;
            while($a< mysqli_num_fields($result)) {
                if(($a == 1)and ($b == 1)){
                    $scheduletext.="<th></th>";
                } else {
                    if (($a == 1) or ($b == 1)) {
                        $scheduletext.="<th>".$row[$a]."</th>";
                    } else {
                        $scheduletext.="<td>".$row[$a]."</td>";   
                    }
                }
                $a++;
            }
            $scheduletext.="</tr>";
            $b++;
        }
    }
    $scheduletext=$scheduletext."</table>";
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TastySnack - Production Schedule</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tasty.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="top-left">
            TastySnack Production
        </div>
        <div id="top-right">
            <img id="logo" src="images/TastysnackLogo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="split"></div>
    <div id="schedule">
        <?php 
            print_r($scheduletext);
        ?> 
        <div id="new"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("td").click(function(){
            $(this).html("<textarea>");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide actual code and not screenshots please.

Comment: `td` and `th` are the only child elements allowed in `tr`. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: make the textarea width smaller with css?

Comment: Here is the code in JSbin.  http://jsbin.com/zaluxazele/edit?html,output
The question is what is my best option for editing text.  <textarea> makes the cell larger and honestly it looks ugly...  <contenteditable> doesnt work with IE from the sounds of it, which disqualifies it as an option.  My end goal is to save the value back to the database also after its entered which is why I was trying a click with jquery, so itd be easy to add more code to shoot the text back to the DB afterwards.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third party site. Also, add the text of your comment to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Just include contenteditable

into the td where evere you want to have content editable

```
 <td contenteditable>hello world</td>
```

**here is a demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/3eav7mLv/

Comment: great idear. just as additional usage info: http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

Comment: Good option but it's harder to implement an onchange event to be fired when the cell content is changed

Comment: here is a very simple tutorial  http://webslesson.blogspot.in/2016/02/live-table-add-edit-delete-using-ajax-jquery-in-php-mysql.html

Comment: Tested and this is supported by Chrome, Firefox 45.0.2, Safari 5.1.7. Not in IE though. Regardless of what caniuse.com says

Comment: If this does not work on IE it would be a no go.  Im using this site for work and some guys here do use IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery table edit.
http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples
for edit and delete.

1. Download and include js table edit file.
2. Use code from example like this:

   ```
   $('#example3').Tabledit({ 
   url: 'example.php',
   editButton: false,
   deleteButton: false,
   hideIdentifier: true,
   columns: {
       identifier: [0, 'id'],
       editable: [[2, 'firstname'], [3, 'lastname']]
   }});
   ```

   Where

> example.php

can be your route for controller with some logic.

Comment: example 3 would be what I was looking for, although i cant seem to figure out exactly how I would incorporate it into my code?  I also wouldnt want the cell size to change like it does when clicked in example 3

Answer (score 0):

just include `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">` tag within the `<td>` tag

```
<td><textarea rows="4" cols="50">Content here</textarea></td>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.